# java.io.File delete() failing in Windows 7 (java newbie)

Tags: java, windows, java-io

I'm new to Java, just trying to make a simple utility to move, copy & delete some wav files on my pc, but java.io.File delete() fails. The wav files in question have read-only unchecked (in windows explorer) but File canWrite() returns false & setWritable(true) fails. I must be doing something stupid because nobody seems to have had this problem before?

Comment: Add some code to your post so we can help you more easily.

Comment: Any chance those files reside in a protected folder, such as Program Files? If so, your app must run as administrator in order to delete files. This might be a Windows permissions issue, not a Java one.

Comment: and also add the error message you get

Comment: Which exception is thrown? Please post the stacktrace also.

Comment: What do you get if you call `file.exists()`.  You are most likely specifyng a relative path and are not in the directory you think you are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a relative path and you are not in the directory you think you are.

Specify absolute paths or determine the current path before starting.

Answer (score 0):

Run the java application as administrator.
Then try.

```
file.setWritable(true);
file.delete();
```

Comment: I am running the java in eclipse. I am logged to windows as administrator. The wav files are in an eclipse workspace.

Comment: File f = new File("./sounds"); 
  String[] s=f.list(); 
  System.out.println("1st file is " + s[0]);
  File f0= new File(s[0]);  
  boolean succeeded =f0.setWritable(true);   
  if(succeeded)
   System.out.println("set writable succeeded");
  else
   System.out.println("set writable failed");
  boolean canWrite =f0.canWrite();  
  boolean deleted=f0.delete();  
  System.out.println("canWrite =" + canWrite + "\n deleted = " + deleted);  
  File f2 = new File("./sounds"); 
  s=f2.list();  
  System.out.println("1st file is now \n \t" + s[0]);

Comment: @user1459584 Don't post code in comments; update your original post.

Comment: @jim you got it:  File cTtor needs full path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the garbage collector:

```
File file = new File("test-file.txt");
System.gc()
boolean success = file.delete();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html