# Deleting specified file

Tags: java, string, file, boolean, delete-file

I'm trying to delete files but it isn't working or I'm missing something.
Here is a little test I'm doing:

```
private void deleteFromDir(String filename) {
    String path = "./test/pacientes/" + filename + ".tds";

    File f = new File(path);

    System.out.println("Abs path " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Exist " + f.exists());
    System.out.println("Filename " + f.getName());
    System.out.println("Delete " + f.delete());

}
```

And the system prints:

> Abs path C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\PAI\TSoft.\test\pacientes\John Smith.tds
>       Exist true
>       Filename John Smith.tds
>       Delete false

And of course isn't deleting the file, why? How can I make it work?

Comment: Files ".tds" are serialized objects

Comment: due to permissions maybe? if the file already exists, then this could be the case

Comment: Does any of the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056856/java-io-file-delete-failing-in-windows-7-java-newbie

Comment: Use `Files.delete(Path)` from nio. If there are any permission issues, it will throw an IOException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps, you do not have the permission to delete this file. You can use the [Files.delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method, which throws an IOException, in case something goes wrong, to see what the real problem is.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, but im getting "java.nio.file.FileSystemException:" because the file is being used by another process. Im following this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905235/java-cannot-delete-file-being-used-by-another-process)

Comment: @Frankovich so, does it work after following the link that you provided? if not, the cause can be that you open this stream in another part of your code, without closing it before this part.

Comment: Yes, i had to close the FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream when deserializing the object in the file. Thanks for your help :)